# Why might ruby fail to recognize that a child process (opened using popen) has terminated?

Tags: ruby, process

The child process is launched using the following code:

```
IO.popen("/path/to/process/in/question") do |command|
    command.each do |line|
        puts line
    end
end
puts "Child Process Complete"
```

The individual lines output by the child process are correctly shown on the console up to and including one immediately before the process exits. However, the message "Child Process Complete" is not shown until I hit *ctrl-c*.

A similar process, triggered using the same mechanism, is correctly recognized as having terminated, so the problem is probably a result of *something* that the child process is doing. Unfortunately I have no idea what that something may be.

[Edit] I should probably also mention that the child process can also be triggered directly from the command prompt, and that no issues are observed when doing so.

Comment: Are you sure the child process is terminated and not waiting for user input?

Comment: Pretty certain. It's a shell script, and the last line in the script before it's supposed to terminate is "Complete". I'm seeing the "Complete" message as expected.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a minimal shell script and add it to your question?

Comment: Unfortunately not (yet). As stated in my question, it appears to be something associated with this specific child process (script) and is not exhibited if I sanitize the script for public viewing. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Benoit Garret](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211840/benoit-garret) put me onto the right track when he suggested that something was waiting for user input. In attempting to sanitize the child process script (and the things it called in turn) I stumbled upon what appeared to be an error in a script lower down (which has been sitting there unnoticed for several years).

The Ruby code, posted above made a call to an initial shell script. That in turn was calling a second shell script which contained the following abomination:

```
(some_application) &
>/dev/null 2>&1
```

I'm not sure if this is what happened, but the way I read this is that some_application gets started and run as a background process. Standard output gets redirected to /dev/null and standard error gets redirected to standard output... *but which process does this redirection relate to*?

Changing the call to

```
some_application >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

(I.e. run some_application throwing away standard out and capturing standard error to the console) made all my problems go away.